# How to get common variables from dataframe through series in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example

```
Name  |    Numbers  |  Mean
Parth | 123         | 1
Nayan | 234         | 1.2
Paul  | 456         |2.3
Rashmi| 567         | 4.3
Anushka|678         | 2.3
Vignesh|789         | 5.6
Mark   | 345        | 9.4
Alavandar|123       | 1.2
```

I have a series of (3,) in `part = ('Mark','Alavandar','Parth')`

I need the data of just that part.

Comment: what do you mean by data of just that part? you want only the rows where that name matches?

Comment: Check [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: @aws_apprentice, yes it is series type which contains only names

Comment: @yatu can you provide me an example?

Comment: `df[df.Name.isin(part)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a DataFrame with only the rows you're interested in like this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Parth', 123, 1],['foo',123,2]], columns=['Name','Numbers','Mean'])
>>> df
    Name  Numbers  Mean
0  Parth      123     1
1    foo      123     2
>>> df[df.Name == 'foo']
  Name  Numbers  Mean
1  foo      123     2
```

You can obviously expand the equality check to iterate over a list (or Series) of values. Remember to assign that operation to a new DataFrame if you will need it again since it returns a new one, like so:

```py
names = ['foo', 'bar']
for name in names:
    df2 = df[df.Name == name]
>>>df2
  Name  Numbers  Mean
1  foo      123     2
```